# How to use custom domain in blogger, not subdomain?

Tags: dns, blogger

I have blog on blogger `example.blogspot.com` and a domain `example.com`.
I tried to use custom domain with blogger and added it to Blogger settings. Now my blog is hosted at:

`blog.example.com`

I want a CNAME or something to point my domain `example.com` to `blog.example.com` or `example.com` as my blog. I don't want the domain to Redirect to subdomain as it is bad for SEO.
I have seen in Google Blogger Support that there is an option for redirect domain to blog's subdomain. But that doesn't appear on my Blogger settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @guerrilla's steps but after 2 days, Address resolution for `example.com` failed. But `www.example.com` was working. So, I found a solution somewhere else on the web! Because the Google Guide asks to create A-Record such that

`example.com` -> `216.239.32.21`

`example.com` -> `216.239.34.21`

`example.com` -> `216.239.36.21`

`example.com` -> `216.239.38.21`

Thats where was the problem.

**Solution:**

1. Use `www.example.com` . The option will appear in Blogger Settings to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`. Check that. (by @guerrillaa)
2. Add Following A-Records:

`@` -> `216.239.32.21`

`@` -> `216.239.34.21`

`@` -> `216.239.36.21`

`@` -> `216.239.38.21`

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `blog.example.com`. Instead use `www.example.com` . The option will appear in Blogger Settings to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.
- [Follow this](https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?p=customdomain&hl=en&rd=1#ts=1734115) to add **A-Records** for `example.com` in your Hosting Provider's DNS section.

Comment: Right! But can't I host the blog on `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`